If $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} f(x)=L, (L\in \mathbb{R})$, $f'(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,+\infty),$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} f'(x)=0$

If $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} f(x)=L, (L\in \mathbb{R})$, $f'(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,+\infty),$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} f'(x)=0$.

$\textbf{Attempt}$:
$\textbf{Claim}$: If $f'(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,+\infty)$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}f'(x)$ exists.
If $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}f'(x)$ does not exist, then there exists $\epsilon>0$, such that for all $M>0$ with $x,y>M$, we have $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq\epsilon$
Since $f'(x)$ is uniformly continuous, there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that for all $x,y\in (0,+\infty)$ with $|x-y|<\delta_1$, we have $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. So, here is a contradiction if we fix $x=x_1>M$ and choose $y=x_1+\frac{\delta_1}{2}$.
Suppose that $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}f'(x)=A$, then $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists M_2>0$, such that for all $x>M_2$, $|f'(x)-A|<\epsilon$
Since $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} f(x)=L$, $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists M_1>0$, such that for all $x,y>M_1$, $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. Fix $x=x_0>\max\{M_1,M_2\}$ and let $y=x_0+1,$ by Lagrange's MVT, there exists $\xi\in (x_0,x_0+1)$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(\xi)|<\epsilon.$
$|f'(x)-A|<\epsilon$ and $|f'(\xi)|<\epsilon$ implies $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} f'(x)=0$.
I am not sure if this proof is correct and whether there is a more succinct one, any help would be appreciated!

No. The application to the very first line is not correct. The first line is not entirely correct either.

If $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}f'(x)$ does not exist, then there exists $\epsilon>0$, such that for all $M>0$ with $x,y>M$, we have $|f(x)-f(y)|>\epsilon$

If $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}f'(x)$ does not exist, then there exists $\epsilon>0$, such that for all choice of $M>0$, there exist $x,y>M$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| \geqslant \epsilon$. Another wording is that there exists $\epsilon>0$ and sequences $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ diverging to infinity such that $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)| \geqslant \epsilon$ for every $n$.

So, here is a contradiction if we fix $x=x_1>M$ and choose $y=x_1+\frac{\delta_1}{2}$.

These sequences are not something to be chosen in your second sentence. You know that they exist that is all.

Thank you for your answer. Why couldn't I choose such $x,y$?

I mean, you can define $x$ and $y$ as such, but it is NOT a contradiction to the first sentence.

But I have proved $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq \epsilon$ at the same time. I am still a little bit confused, could you elaborate on that?

Your first sentence is not correct. The correct sentence is written in the answer, which shows there exists $x$, $y$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$. If you find a pair which does not satisfy the condition, there is no contradiction.

Get your idea, thank you very much.

For an alternative proof:
Suppose that there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that, for every $x>0$ there is $y>x$ with $|f'(y)|>\epsilon$.
Given that $f'$ is uniformly continuous, there is some $\delta$ such that $$|x-y|<\delta\implies |f'(x)-f'(y)|<\epsilon/2$$
As $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=L$, there is some $x_0>0$ such that $$L-\frac{\delta\epsilon}{4}<f(x)<L+\frac{\delta\epsilon}{4}, \quad x>x_0$$
We know there exists some $y>x_0$ with $|f'(y)|>\epsilon$, and that $$|f'(x)-f'(y)|<\epsilon/2,\quad x\in [y,y+\delta]$$
This implies that $|f'(x)|>\epsilon/2$ for $x\in [y,y+\delta]$.
By continuity of $f'$, it is either always positive or always negative in that interval. In any case, $f$ increases or decreases with a rate bigger than $\epsilon/2$ in an interval of length $\delta$, so that $$|f(y+\delta)-f(y)|>\frac{\delta\epsilon}{2}$$
Given that $f(y)\in (L-\frac{\delta\epsilon}{4},L+\frac{\delta\epsilon}{4})$, an interval of length $\frac{\delta\epsilon}{2}$, we find that $$f(y+\delta)\notin \left(L-\frac{\delta\epsilon}{4},L+\frac{\delta\epsilon}{4}\right) ,$$
a contradiction.

Thank you for your answer.

As already pointed out in 温泽海's answer, your argument that the uniform continuity of $f'$ implies the existence of $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ is not correct.
One can argue as follows: Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given.

From the uniform continuity of $f'$ we get a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-y| < \delta$ implies $|f'(x) -f'(y)| < \epsilon$.
From $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$ we we get a $K \in \Bbb R$ such that $x > K$ implies $|f(x) - L| < \frac 12 \delta \epsilon $.

Then we have for all $x > K$
$$
 \delta \epsilon > |f(x+\delta) - L| + |f(x)-L| \\
 \ge |f(x+\delta) - f(x)|  = \delta |f'(c)|
$$
with some $c$ between $x$ and $x+\delta$. It follows that $|f'(x)| < \epsilon$ and
$$
 |f'(x)| \le |f'(c)| + |f'(c) - f'(x)| < \epsilon + \epsilon = 2 \epsilon
$$
and that concludes the proof.

Thank you for your answer.

This result is so-called Barbalat's Lemma.
Proof:
Suppose $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}f'(x)\neq0,$ (here I mean that the limit exists but is not zero, or the limit does not exist)
then there exists $\epsilon_0>0$ and a monotone increasing
sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_n\to+\infty$ as $n\to\infty$
and $|f'(x_n)|\geq2\epsilon_0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Since $f'$ is uniformly continuous, for such $\epsilon_0$,
there exists $\delta_0>0$ such that for $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$|x-x_n|\leq\delta_0\implies|f'(x)-f'(x_n)|\leq\epsilon_0.$$
Hence if $x\in[x_n,x_n+\delta_0]$, then
$$|f'(x)|\geq|f'(x_n)|-|f'(x_n)-f'(x)|\geq\epsilon_0.$$
By MVT,
$$0=\lim_{n\to\infty}|f(x_n+\delta_0)-f(x_n)|
=\lim_{n\to\infty}|f'(\xi_n)|\delta_0\geq\epsilon_0\delta_0.$$
This is a contradiction. Therefore $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}f'(x)=0.$

Thank you. Shake hands!

@
Martin R
$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f'(x)\neq0$ means that the limit does not exist, or exists with a nonzero limit.

@
Martin R
Actually, if the limit exists, it is easy to get  the limit is $0$: $$f'(\xi_n)=f(n+1)-f(n)\to0,\ n\to\infty.$$
